# php using variable as actual argument in php function

Tags: php, function, variables

Below is my code.  In the first half of my code you will see the variables $question and $row.  When I echo $question and/or $row[0] I get values returned.  However, at the bottom of the code I try to use these to variables as actual arguments in the add_textbox function.  However,  the add_textbox function is acting like those variables are null.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
<?php


$dbhost = 'localhost';

$uname = $_POST["uname"];

//***create connection object
$connection = mysql_connect($dbhost, "bc572482", "dfdfdfs")
    or die (mysql_error());

$dbname = "bc57";
mysql_select_db($dbname)
    or die (mysql_error());
```

//***select a random security question

```
//*** need this to import session variables
 session_start();

// echo ($_SESSION["ValidUser"] . '<br>');
 $uname =$_SESSION["ValidUser"];
  //echo ($uname . '<br>');

$rq = array('q1','q2','q3');
  $rand_key = array_rand($rq,1);
 // echo $rq[$rand_key];

 $question = $rq[$rand_key];

 $qtoanswer = mysql_query("select $question from users where uname = '$uname'");
 if(!$qtoanswer)
 {
    echo "Could not run query:"  . mysql_error();
    exit;
  }

 //echo ($qtoanswer . '<br>');
 $row = mysql_fetch_row($qtoanswer);

 //echo ($row[0] . abc);

 display_security();


 //functions to create security page
 function myprint($text)
 {
    print("$text \n");
 }

 //*** a bit of style
function add_style() 
{
  myprint("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href= \"main.css\" />");
 //myprint("<style type=text/css> * {font-family:arial;}   h3 {color:orange} </style>");
 }

//*** add a text box
function add_textbox($label, $name) 
{
   myprint("$label <br><input type=text name=$name><br>");
 }

   function add_submit($label) 
{
   myprint("<input type=submit name=submit value=$label>");
   myprint("<input type=reset value=Reset><br>");

}

//create the dynamic security page
function display_security()
{
    myprint("<html><head>");
    add_style();
    myprint("</head><body>");
    myprint("<h3> Feeding our Brothers and Sisters <br> Security Check</h3>"); 
    // get the security form created
    myprint("<form name=securityForm method=post action=login.php>");

     add_textbox($row[0],$question);
     add_submit("Login");


 myprint("</form>");

    myprint("</body></html>");

}
```

?>

Comment: Those variables are not defined inside of function `display_security()` within which you are calling `add_textbox()`

Comment: I don't see that you are passing those variables as arguments in any of your functions.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `$row[0]` and `$question` as function parameter when call the `display_security()` function like this

```
display_security($row[0], $question);
```

In `display_security()` use the parameter variables `$p` & `$question`

```
function display_security($p, $question)
{
    myprint("<html><head>");
    add_style();
    myprint("</head><body>");
    myprint("<h3> Feeding our Brothers and Sisters <br> Security Check</h3>");
    // get the security form created
    myprint("<form name=securityForm method=post action=login.php>");
    add_textbox($p,$question);
                ^^^ ^^^^^^^^
    add_submit("Login");
    myprint("</form>");
    myprint("</body></html>");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$question` and `$row` are global variables. Into the function, `$question` and `$row` are local variables not global. You can call to [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) or the [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword:

```
$question = 'this is a global variable';
$row = 'this is a global variable too';

function foo() {
    global $row;
    global $question;
    add_textbox($row[0], $question);
}
```

Comment: The use of `global` is highly discouraged; it's better practice to pass variables explicitly into the scope of your function.

Comment: Yes Jack, it's true. It's a bad practice... like using mysql instead of mysqli and embedding HTML code in PHP files... like using several parameters in a function (see Martin Fowler's refactoring notes). Both solutions are bad practice but it's true that pass vars like arguments is not too bad like use globals.